# Rails-JQuery-Autocomplete search multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I'm using the [rails-jquery-autocomplete gem](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) to find a customer in a form.
Controller

```
class RfqsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :customer, :name, full:true
```

view file

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :customer %>
    <%=  f.autocomplete_field :customer, :autocomplete_customer_name %>
    <%= link_to "new customer", new_customer_path, class: "new_customer_link"%>
  </div>
```

Currently, It only searches by the customer name.  I would like to have it search by the company as well. I'm new to rails but I think I need to use scopes but I'm not sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Extra_data**

From the link you have provided https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete
By default, your search will only return the required columns from the database 
needed to populate your form, namely id and the column you are searching (name, in the above example).

Passing an array of attributes/column names to this option will fetch and return the specified data.

```
class ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :brand, :name, :extra_data => [:slogan]
end

so in your case


autocomplete :customer, :name, full:true, :extra_data => [:company_name]

def company_name
 company.name
end
```

Comment: I know it's my fault and your answer is very complete. But I forgot to mention that the company is a separate model.  The customer belongs_to company.  Can your answer be adjusted for that?

Comment: @suavocado, adding a function company_name would do the trick